# Eureka server not working properly, after while

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have faced some wired issue with Eureka discovery server. My project is developed in Springboot with eureka, zuul, ribbon and It deployed on GCP kubernetes cluster. In the begining it works fine. But after two or three days, some times it is unable to identify the client servers. If I try again and again it will work. Client services gives following error for only some requests.

```
I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Here is my configurations.

Discovery Server application.properties file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

server:
  port: 8070

eureka:
  environment: production
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    service-url:
      defaultZone : ${DIS_SERVER}
```

Zuul Gateway application.properties file

```
 zuul:
  prefix: /api/v1
  routes:
    g1-server:
      path: /g1/**
      serviceId: G1-SERVER
    g2-server:
      path: /g2/**
      serviceId: G2-SERVER

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server

server:
  port: 5000

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone : ${DIS_SERVER}

spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignored-interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
        - eth2
        - eth3
        - lo
        - veth.*

ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 200000
  ReadTimeout: 200000
```

I have used restTemplate to call other microservices. following code shows how I use the resTemplate to call other microservices.

```
String g1Url = "http://g1-server/ud/{id}";
String g1Response = restTemplate.getForObject(g1Url, String.class, id);
```

When I restart the discovery server everything works fine again. Where did I went wrong ?